# time-critical application with Python on Windows

Tags: python-2.7, windows-10, time-critical

I run a time-critical application on Windows 10 using Python 2.7x. And it seems Windows sometimes interrupts my program for a fraction of a seconds. This happens every like 5 - 10 seconds.

How can I "tell" Windows that my program is the only thing which is important as long as it is running?

Comment: Did you try this: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496767-set-process-priority-in-windows/ ?

Comment: yes but I got an error that win32api, win32process, win32con cannot be imported? Are these modules still up-to-date..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I wasn't clear about my link; I meant the `psutil` usage as proposed in the second comment on http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496767-set-process-priority-in-windows/:

```
import psutil, os
p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print(p.nice())
p.nice(psutil.HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS)
print(p.nice())
```

... yields:

```
32
128
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I'll check and respond in the evening!